Constant harassment and false accusations on bitcoin stackexchange

Accused of being a sockpuppet account created by Samourai: How does dumplings work?
Neither Wasabi nor NBitcoin support Signet. I created a transaction on signet that is detected as coinjoin by dumplings and  shared the steps to reproduce. This proves there can be false positives and its easy to create fake coinjoin that dumplings would count as coinjoin.

Accused of being sockpuppet again and some agenda in the comments Wasabi Wallet 2.0 coin control. How secure / private are sent coins now?
The question was about coin control in Wasabi and I shared all the details with a screenshot. There was a disclaimer added with link to the post written by zkSNACKs team as a newbie reading the answer should be aware of such red flags.


Is it okay to accuse random people on bitcoin stackexchange of something based on your feelings? Can I do the same everytime nopara73 writes something on bitcoin stackexchange?
I am not sure if bitcoin stackexchange requires KYC but I can prove my identity to one of the moderators if its kept conifdential, nopara73 can apologize publicly and stop writing false things about anons online.

Thanks for the heads-up. I responded to each of the three comments and communicated expectations for acceptable behavior. Please let us know if this happens again.

Thank you Murch
